# Rich Multimedia Application - WPF or some DirectX wrapper?

Tags: c#, wpf, directx, multimedia

For developing a rich multimedia application for Windows 7 and above, I am trying to figure out which technology should I use. I want to develop it completely using WPF but I doubt if its possible, DirectX obviously gives me power to do what I want to but I don't want to use some Managed DirectX wrapper(SlimDX/SharpDX etc) as my target language will be C#. Features will be like playing videos, images, applying effects/transitions using pixel shader, playing DVDs, playing multiple videos/images/shapes at once etc.

So I have basically two questions, 1) What Do you guys suggest I should go with? 2) Can I develop it completely using WPF?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like most of what you want to achieve can be implemented with WPF. WPF actually has 3D rendering capabilities. It really depends on how complicated the application is going to be, specifically the graphics side of it. Here are a few handy links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742562.aspx#rendering

http://wpffx.codeplex.com/

[Is WPF 3D good alternate of DirectX and OpenGL for complex applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941383/is-wpf-3d-good-alternate-of-directx-and-opengl-for-complex-applications)

[DirectX and WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912469/directx-and-wpf)

Comment: Jess, Thanks for looking, I am aware of using Pixel Shader & 3D in WPF, and I have some experience with these as well, but problem areas for me are DVD playback, and Media Element does not look really good to me as it fails after repeatedly changing source. Do you think it can go well with these issue?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have much experience in this particular area, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything that you mentioned in your question in WPF. It provides many useful controls for displaying audio and video media. The only thing that you mentioned that is *not* widely available in WPF is pixel shading, but this *can* be built in.

I have an excellent book that covers this topic and as luck would have it, I found a PDF of it that someone has put online: Take a look at chapter 13 in the [WPF control development unleashed: building advanced user experiences](http://www.adorkable.us/books/wpf_control_development.pdf) PDF.

Comment: Sheridan, Thanks for your response, WPF have great support for pixel shader as I have already worked with that. As I mentioned I could not find anything about DVD playback in WPF, also I am worried about MediaElement as it looks performing poor. Do you have any suggestions about these?

Comment: Yeah, it's a good book. Take a look at the [WPF MediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/) for handling DVDs. With regards to playing audio and video, I've never had any problems while using the `MediaElement` control, but then I've only used them in fairly simple set ups.

Comment: Yup. I was going through WPF MediaKit. And MediaElement causes trouble when we tries to change source multiple time to be able to play multiple videos one after another.